# Determining the most used value in an array

Tags: c++

I am needing to write an application that determines the value that comes up most often in an array in C++ and its position in the array.

For example, if I have an array A where

```
A[0] = 3    A[1] = 4    A[2] =  3
A[3] = 2    A[4] = 3    A[5] = -1
A[6] = 3    A[7] = 3
```

I must determine that 3 is the most often used number and am required to return the position in the array it occurs.  Any position is fine.  For example, 0,2,4,6,7 are all valid solutions.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such if it is.

Comment: Smells like a homework problem.  I will suggest you look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/ -- you can build up a map from (value)->(number of occurrences) to find the most frequently used value.

Comment: is the range of the numbers limited?

Comment: If the elements are in a small, known range (-5 to 5), you can use an array `int counts[11]` instead of a map for a speed boost.  Otherwise, use a `std::map<int,int>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One is to sort the array, so that you can count all similar values at once. Another is to use an associative array, a.k.a. a dictionary, where the values from A are keys and frequencies are the values associated with the keys.

Comment: Which is faster, in terms of complexity?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a [`map<int,int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to count the frequency of each element.  Then use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) with a custom function that compares the pair elements of the map by value.  Then I would just use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) on the array to find the first match.